# Is there a way to stop Google sheets from telling me to use Ctrl C?

Tags: google-sheets

I know the keyboard shortcuts for cut, copy and paste, and I use them frequently. But there are times when using the mouse is much more convenient. Especially if I want to copy a whole row, I prefer to not select it with the left button and then copy with the keyboard, but select it with the right mouse button and directly choose "copy" from the context menu. In other cases, I'm not sure the focus is on the window in which the current selection is, so I right click on the selection to make sure I'll copy what I want.

But Google sheets is determined to admonish me to use the keyboard shortcuts every single time, breaking my flow with a modal dialog. I can understand why they think they are doing novice users a favor by teaching them this, but when I know what I'm doing, it becomes very annoying. At least Clippy didn't use modal dialogs.

Is there a setting hidden somewhere to just tell them "Please stop showing me this advice"?

Comment: I don't use google Sheets, but I did just go try this, and the OP is correct it's a very annoying dialog without a "don't show me this again" or as google seems to like a "got it!" button.