# Google docs produces a pop up when copying and pasting nearly every time

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox

When I copy and paste into google docs it almost always (3 times out of 4) produces the following box even when I use the keyboard shortcuts (on firefox). Is there any way to permanently tell it to stop reminding me as it really gets in the way of my workflow?

[image: Annoying message displayed by google docs]

Comment: This is the way it operates throughout the GSuite program set. It is annoying for sure but I now automatically use Ctrl+C and CTRL+V for copying and pasting by default in Google. I don't think there is a way of suppressing it.

Comment: Never seen this window. Maybe try to tick off and on "Enable compatible spreadsheet shortcuts"  in Help\Keyboard Shortcuts

Comment: @User24601 Yeah i am using the keyboard shortcuts, that's why its so annoying. It doesn't even appear every time I just have to spam ctrl+v until it works

Comment: Related [In copy/paste, Google Docs says “These actions are unavailable via the Edit menu, but you can still use Ctrl C” etc?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40147/88163), [Is there a way to stop Google sheets from telling me to use Ctrl C?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/73218/88163)

Comment: Enabling compatible shortcuts as per @Oleg_S's comment worked for me in Edge Chromium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Workspace Editors (Docs, Drawings, Forms, Sheets, Slides) doesn't includ a setting for that. Please send your feedback directly to Google. You can do this from the Help menu in any on these apps.

It's worthy to note that this doesn't happen when Chrome is used.